# .mp4 links fail to open, and other minor things in 10.0.10

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, settings, troubleshooting

Since a few days ago, can't pinpoint the date, `.mp4` links fail to open; `.webm` play fine. These are links to straight `.mp4` files, not through custom players, or anything, and they did play before with the browser's native player. Now, opening them in a new tab, instead of a tab with the NoScript block waiting to be unlocked, all there is is an empty tab, as if there's not even a canvas; it's only the window colour (as defined in the window manager). BTW, this is Tor browser 10.0.10 in Archlinux x64 (official archive). The settings are set to no javascript, safest level (except when it's really needed, like now, when it's on "safer"), plus various other settings found on [privacytools.io](https://www.privacytools.io/).

This is how it looks like when opening a new tab, normally:

[image: normal]

and this is when I try to open a link:

[image: now]

The `media` should still be blocked by NoScript, the overlay should have appeared, but there isn't. I notice there is traffic going on, the browser tries to buffer something, but nothing happens. I tried searching through `about:config`, but there doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary. The NoScript extension shows it has been updated "Feb 4th", so around the time when TB had an update, (more or less).

Does this happen because of the TB or the NoScript? But, more importantly, what can be done to fix it?

In addition, there are sites that don't display correctly, anymore. One of the is github. I can post screenshots, if needed. And the scrollbar now, when clicked, it doesn't scroll page by page, instead it goes where the mouse clicked. This is not how the desktop environment behaves (Xfce).

---

Minor update: searching for browser test pages, I found [this](https://midimusic.github.io/browsertest/). Towards the middle of the page there is a section *Diagnostic Videos*. Opening the [mp4](https://midimusic.github.io/browsertest/mp4video.html) link displays this:

[image: nothing]

Nothing plays. The other media links are opened normally, with NoScript overlay which, removed, allows normal playback. Firefox has no problems.

Given [Steve's comment below](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22027/mp4-links-fail-to-open-and-other-minor-things-in-10-0-10#comment23543_22027) (and the reply), there may be a possibility that my system is lacking something. So what codecs does TB use and how can I check for those in my system?

Comment: On Ubuntu with 10.0.10 the [URL](https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4) works for me on the "Safest" setting (the NoScript overlay appears, I click accept, and the video plays). Can you try downloading a fresh copy of Tor Browser with no configuration changes and check if it plays the video?

Comment: @Steve It doesn't work. Now I'm worried. I checked `.pacman -Qs ffmpeg` and it shows there is `ffmpeg` and `gst-libav`, so there should be codecs? Or is TB using something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does it work in Firefox? If it worked on a previous version but doesn't on a fresh installed latest version, then I would recommend making a bug report here: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues

Comment: @Steve It works on Firefox. Thank you for the link, but if it works for you and we're using the same archive/version then I'm a bit reluctant to use the bug report, at least until I determine whether it's my system, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest update to 10.0.13 corrected this behaviour.

Unfortunately, NoScript still doesn't set `javascript.enabled` to `true` when setting the security to "safer", manual setting is needed through `about:config` (and when going back to "safest"). But that's a minor inconvenience, possibly safer.